# In R, how to filter data by row from already split groups?

Tags: r, split

So I split my data set up into several groups, and I want to know how to find rows that are greater than or equal to the value 70 from the percentage column (note: there are other columns in the data frame, they are just not shown)

```
gdata <- split(data, Opportunity.Name)
```

Dataframe looks like this (with much more groups):

```
Opportunity.Name:    Percentage
Bob                  50
Bob                  60
Bob                  20
Bob                  80
Bob                  90
Bob                  100
Jon                  100
Jon                  90

gdata$'Bob'     
Opportunity.Name  Percentage
Bob                  50
Bob                  60
Bob                  20
Bob                  80
Bob                  90
Bob                  100
```

I would like to apply some function that allows me to filter out the 50, 60, and 20 percentage rows and keep the other values (and have it do it for all of the groups I created). Thanks!

Comment: "So I split my data set up into several groups" - why? There aren't many cases where it's worth doing that (and certainly not to do the calculations you ask for).

Comment: I need to calculate medians/means/sums by opportunity name and then later take more medians/means/sums of the entire set of data. If there is an easier/alternate way, I'd love to know!!

Comment: Yes, there are much better ways, one would be using `data.table`. Something along the lines of `dt = data.table(your_df); dt[, list(mean.person = mean(Percentage), median.person = median(Percentage)), by = Opportunity][, list(mean.total = mean(mean.person))]`; search around SO and google about `data.table` and if you have questions - you know where SO is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(gdata, function(x){x[x$Percentage>=70,]})
```

Gives:

```
$Bob
  Opportunity.Name Percentage
4              Bob         80
5              Bob         90

$Jon
  Opportunity.Name Percentage
6              Jon        100
7              Jon         90
```

UPDATE: To keep records where the percentage is zero, add an `or` clause with the pipe operator:

```
lapply(gdata, function(x){x[x$Percentage>=70 | x$Percentage==0,]})
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, you can use `subset` syntax to achieve the same result:

```
lapply(gdata, function(x){subset(x, Percentage>=70 | Percentage==0)})
```

Comment: It looks good! Is there also a way to keep a certain value? (I want to have all values greater than or equal to 70 AND keep the value of 0)

Answer (score 0):

if you were very specific about what values you did not want you could use

```
d <- subset(gdata, Percentage != 50 & Percentage != 60 & Percentage !=20)
```

Comment: 1) gdata is a list, not a dataframe. But you could apply this subsetting to the `data` object and then `split` that to get the desired result. 2) why not just do `Percentage >= 70` instead of and-ing together a bunch of `!=` clauses?

Comment: I meant this option if the user wanted to remove rows with specific percent values. The question was not clear on whether it was values lesser than 70 percent.

Comment: Actually, the "greater than or equal to 70" specification was provided in the first line of the question. And still, your solution would return an error because you can't use subset on a list, which is what the gdata object is.